# TestNG building both classes, why?

Tags: java, webdriver, testng

Im having some problems with my WebDriver project. Its my first and ill try to explain as good as i can.

I have this TestNG XML file:

```
<suite name="Automated test">
<test name="Running all tests for browser Chrome">
<parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
<classes>
    <class name="TEST_Login" />
    <class name="TEST_Navigation" />
</classes>
```

This is just an example, there will be many other classes listed.

In these classes i build the RemoteWebDriver

TEST_Login file.

```
@Parameters({"browser"})
public TEST_Login(String browser) throws MalformedURLException 
{
    CONF_Setup test = new CONF_Setup();
    this.driver     = test.setup(browser);
}
```

This file calls the config file where i build the RemoteWebDriver. After this class has finished its tests, i close the driver with the @AfterMethod annotation.

The problem that i have is that in all my TEST_xxx classes i build a new RemoteWebDriver. When i execute the test via the TestNG XML file it tries to build both instances of RemoteWebDriver, this means that the test will not run. The browser opens but thats it.

Is there any other way to make TestNG wait building the other classes before the one before has closed? If not, does anyone have a good solution to my problem?

Kind regards :)

Comment: Have you tried setting on the TestNG <suite /> level parallel="false"?

Comment: I've tried this, but it did not work: <suite name="Automated test" parallel="false"> It still tries to launch the remotewebdriver two times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by not building RemoteWebDriver in each class but in a separate config class